# Scaling my app for a 3.5 inch screen

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've almost completed my first app and made it with the 4 inch iPhone screen in mind.

It only works in potrait mode and isn't graphics heavy. I want it to work on the iphone 4 and 4s which have 3.5 inch screens. Right now when I run the app in simulator, it just cuts a bit off the bottom to accommodate the 3.5 inch screen.

Is there a way I can just get all my buttons and labels to vertically shrink a little to work on the 3.5 inch display?

What's the easiest and best practice in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way I handle the 3.5 inch vs 4 inch screen is making two separate .xib files and load the appropriate one using this check:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        //Load 3.5 inch xib
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        //Load 4 inch xib
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've seen that method but i'm using storyboards.

I think I may have found a solution playing around with xcode though. I set the size of my view to inferred in the simulated metrics. I then went to each label, button etc and in the size inspector, clicked on the vertical arrows and removed the red bar that specifies a fixed distance from the vertical edges. 

This seems to scale everything vertically in the simulator when in 3.5 inch mode.

Can anyone see any problems in me using this method?