# How to make a view fit 3.5 and 4 inch screen

Tags: ios, screen-size

I am using Xcode 5 and am making a game for the iPhone. I would like my app to be available on both the 3.5 and 4 inch screen but when I set it to the 3.5 0.5 inches are cut off so the player can't play my game. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling my app for a 3.5 inch screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084325/scaling-my-app-for-a-3-5-inch-screen)

Answer (score 4):

Use **Autolayout**. Reference: [Autolayout introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Autolayout allows you to set up views to adapt to the screen size automatically based on a set of rules you provide. It's a very powerful technique, once you get how it works (which can take a little while).

> Auto Layout is a system that lets you lay out your app’s user interface by creating a mathematical description of the relationships between the elements. You define these relationships in terms of constraints either on individual elements, or between sets of elements. Using Auto Layout, you can create a dynamic and versatile interface that responds appropriately to changes in screen size, device orientation, and localization.